# How to display product details when the image is clicked in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

I've made a website that displays all products with images. Now what I'm trying to figure out is, how to make the image clickable and when the image is clicked it displays the product information page? Thank you for your help! :)

This is my product.php page.

```
<?php
  include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php'; 
?>

<body>
  <!--- featured products --->
  <div class="small-container">
    <div class="row row-2">
      <h2 class="title"> Featured Products</h2>
      <select>
        <option>Default</option>
        <option>By Price</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cakes;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck > 0 ) {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            ?>
            <div class="col-4">
              <a href="product details.php"><img src= <?php echo $row['image'];?>></a>
              <h4><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h4>
              <p>$<?php echo $row['price']; ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php
          }
        }
      ?>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Below is my database.

[image: This is my database.]

Comment: Just add the id to the product_details.php and when this page is called, you fetch the id to get the contents from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this:

```
<div class="col-4">
        <a href="product details.php"><img src= <?php echo $row['image'];?>></a>
        <h4><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h4>
        <p>$<?php echo $row['price']; ?></p>
    </div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="col-4">
        <a href="product details.php?id_cakes=<?=$row['id']?>""><img src= <?php echo $row['image'];?>></a>
        <h4><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h4>
        <p>$<?php echo $row['price']; ?></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the double-quote on href. Just do it yourself.